# What happens if you kill January?

Tags: prey

In one of the missions in Prey, you go to meet December.  However,

> just as you get there, January kills December.

However, it's possible to kill January before then - there's even [an achievement for it](https://www.trueachievements.com/a233723/suicide-by-proxy-achievement).  What happens in that case?

Comment: I'm very confused by this question and answer... I guess "December" and "January" are names of characters?

Comment: @FabianRöling, yes, "December" and "January" are the names of two special AIs in the game. There's also "October", but you never actually meet it. Their names come from the date they were created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

December "takes place" of January, but instead of pushing you towards the destruction of Talos I he/she will push you towards the escape in Alex's escape pod (false ending). Other than that - no differences in gameplay.

Comment: I'd say it's a pretty significant difference in plot, though. And it's awesome that the devs thought of that!

Comment: Is January's ending still available though? I assume you can loot the necessary item(s) near the end.